# Login System, Using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is take my code and edit it so I can save created user profiles into a database which I haven't yet created. How would I do this?

I also would like to create a content management system to allow me to edit add search and delete users in the database is this possible and how would I do this?

Here is my Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head><body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Please Login
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{

 if(form.userid.value == "Stephen" && form.pswrd.value == "Steveman22")
  {
    window.open('target.html')
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error Password or Username Required")
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out a server side technology such as PHP, ASP or even node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do clientside.

What you can do:

- store info in the local storage as local db. Interested for you, not?

Authentication logic client side makes not sense. Your clientside code is public, so your credentials too.